# While using a dialogflow mega-agent, according to a user setting I want to be able to query a specific sub agent at a time

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

While using a dialogflow mega-agent, according to a user setting I want to be able to query a specific sub agent at a time. I have 3 sub agents. Each subagent has similar training phrases but should request different data. The user should be able to select which sub agent they want to use and the query should only go to the selected subagent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify one or more sub-agents for a detect intent request, set the `subAgents` field of [`QueryParameters`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/QueryParameters).

For example:

```
{
  "queryInput": {
    "text": {
      "text": "reserve a meeting room for six people",
      "languageCode": "en-US"
    }
  },
  "queryParams": {
    "subAgents": [
       {"project": "projects/sub-agent-1-project-id"},
       {"project": "projects/sub-agent-2-project-id"}
    ]
  }
}
```

For more information on Dialogflow ES mega agents, see the [Mega agents documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/agents-mega).

Comment: Awesome thank you, however if I say a phrase similiar to an intent in the desired sub agent, the other agent still gets called